# Tips or Tools for Snapshotting an Open Web Page into Plunkr?

Tags: debugging, jsfiddle, plunker

It's not uncommon for me to get stuck on some issue in my running web application and wish I could just make a quick one-off Plunkr (or jsfiddle) from the total set of the browser's script, style, and HTML SO THAT I can easily tweak and play with things in an instant-feedback environment.  Are there any tools (browser extensions, perhaps) (or techniques) that would facilitate making a Plunkr in this way?